# undefined method `name_t' for {:id=>1, :name_t=>"Y/N"}:Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This code

```
new_hash = [{:id=>1,:name_t=>"Y/N"},{:id=>2,:name_t=>'Number'},{:id=>3,:name_t=>'Text'}]
collection_select(:question,:q_type, new_hash ,:id,:name_t )
```

is throwing the error 
``` undefined method ``name_t' for {:id=>1, :name_t=>"Y/N"}:Hash ```

And is driving me crazy

**Update**

I'm trying to add a DRY static dropdown menu to a form

```
= form_for @question do |f|
  - if @question.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this question from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .row{:style=>"margin-bottom: 5px"}
    .col-xs-2
      = f.label :pm_type
    .col-xs-2
      = f.collection_select(:pm_type_id, PmType.all.where(:is_active => true), :id, :name) 
  .row{:style=>"margin-bottom: 5px"}
    .col-xs-2
      = f.label :proposition
    .col-xs-2
      = f.text_field :proposition
  .row{:style=>"margin-bottom: 5px"}
    .col-xs-2
      = f.label "Type"
    .col-xs-2

      -# ######## Code goes here ##########
      - new_hash = [{:id=>1,:name_t=>"Y/N"},{:id=>2,:name_t=>'Number'},{:id=>3,:name_t=>'Text'}]
      = collection_select(:question,:q_type, new_hash ,:id,:name_t )

  .row{:style=>"margin-bottom: 5px"}
    .col-xs-2
      = f.label "Weight"
    .col-xs-2
      = f.text_field :q_weight
  .row{:style=>"margin-bottom: 5px"}
    .col-xs-2
      = f.label "Active?"
    .col-xs-2
      = check_box_tag(:is_active, 1 ,true)
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Comment: Can you share the body of `collection_select` method?

Comment: like from rails? hm let me see where can i find it

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Get one of the elements? Or filtering?

Comment: Extended my comment with an example. In this way you can pass `name_t` as a method.

Comment: If my answer can help you solve the problem pls accept my answer as solution. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) the fifth parameter of `collection_select` should be a method.

From the api-doc:

> > The `:value_method` and `:text_method` parameters are methods to be called on each member of collection.

Since `name_t` is a key of the element in the array you cannot use it as a method.

But you can try this:

```
class MyType < Struct.new(:id, :name_t)
end

new_hash = [MyType.new(1,"Y/N"),MyType.new(2,"Number"),MyType.new(2,"Text")]
p new_hash[0].name_t
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! i found the [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) method while looking at the documentation, and end up doing the following:

```
select(:question,:q_type, [["Y/N",1],['Number',2],['Text',3]], {} )
```